# Films and x-ray scanning in airports

Tags: film

What can I possible do, when travelling using airports and carrying films in my hand baggage. I am going to Berlin and I want to carry 2 films one Portra 160ASA and one Kodak TMAX 400ASA. What could I possible do during checking my hand baggage? Does x-ray harm films under 800ASA? Is there a difference between coloful and black and white film? Is there any difference between exposed and unexposed film? I am going to travel from Brussels to Berlin and vice versa.